# Consider defining a bean of type 'com.jd.springdata.product.KlientJDBCTemplate' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to run spring application connected to local MySQL server and I'm facing error I can't resolve myself.

```
Description:
```

Field klientJDBCTemplate in com.jd.springdata.product.StartApplication required a bean of type 'com.jd.springdata.product.KlientJDBCTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.jd.springdata.product.KlientJDBCTemplate' in your configuration.

Code of Klient JDBC class

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
public class KlientJDBCTemplate implements KlientDAO { 
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) { 
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }   
    public void insert(String name, Integer age) {
        String SQL = "insert into Klient (name, age) values (?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, name, age);
        System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);
        return;
    }
    public Klient findByid(Integer id) {
        String SQL = "select * from Klient where id = ?";
        Klient klient = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, new KlientRowMapper(), id);
        return klient; 
    }
    public List<Klient> listaKlientow() {
        String SQL = "select * from Klient";
        List <Klient> klienci = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new KlientRowMapper());
        return klienci;
    }
    public void delete(Integer id) {
        String SQL = "delete from Klient where id = ?"; 
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id); 
        System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id ); 
        return;
    }   
    public void update(Integer id, Integer age) {
        String SQL = "update Klient set age = ? where id = ?"; 
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, age, id); 
        System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id ); 
        return;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartApplication implements CommandLineRunner { 
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartApplication.class);
    @Autowired 
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    KlientJDBCTemplate klientJDBCTemplate ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println("StartApplication..."); 
        log.info("StartApplication...");
        startCustomerApp();
    }
    void startCustomerApp() {
        System.out.println("------Wstawianie rekordów z danymi--------" );
        log.info("------Wstawianie rekordów z danymi--------"); 
        klientJDBCTemplate.insert("Adam", 11); 
        klientJDBCTemplate.insert("Jan", 2); 
        klientJDBCTemplate.insert("Robert", 15);
        System.out.println("------Lista wielu rekordow--------" ); 
        log.info("------Lista wielu rekordow--------"); 
        List<Klient> klienci = klientJDBCTemplate.listaKlientow();
        for (Klient record : klienci) {
            System.out.print("ID : " + record.getId() ); 
            System.out.print(", Name : " + record.getName() ); 
            System.out.println(", Age : " + record.getAge() );
        }
        System.out.println("---- Modyfikacja wiersza z ID = 2 -----" );
        log.info("------ Modyfikacja wiersza z ID = 2 --------"); 
        klientJDBCTemplate.update(2, 20);
        System.out.println("----Wylistowanie wiersza z ID = 2 -----" );
        log.info("------ Wylistowanie wiersza z ID = 2 --------"); 
        Klient klient = klientJDBCTemplate.findByid(2); System.out.print("ID : " + klient.getId() ); 
        System.out.print(", Name : " + klient.getName() ); System.out.println(", Age : " + klient.getAge());
            jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE klient IF EXISTS");
            jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE klient(" + "id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(100), age INTEGER)");
    } 
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Kontakty
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jd.springdata.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>lekcja8</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>lekcja8</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Try to add `@Componnet` or `@Service` annotation on your `KlientJDBCTemplate` class

Comment: @Prebiusta Now I'm getting null pointer like this bellow 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.jd.springdata.product.KlientJDBCTemplate.insert(KlientJDBCTemplate.java:21) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: Where are you initializing `jdbcTemplateObject` object? It tries to invoke `insert()` method, on non initialized object.

Comment: You can add `@Autowired` annotation on top of this one too